# Trouble implementing the "Radial reaction" Material Design pattern from Material Design spec using Cards and subclassed RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, material-design, android-recyclerview

[The "Radial reaction" Material Design pattern can be found here.](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B3T7oTWa3HiFdWhpd296VUhLTFk/animation_responsiveinteraction_radialreaction.webm)

Right now, I am using a Subclassed implementation of RecyclerView to automatically provide the right number of rows and columns of Cards depending on the size of the device. In that implementation of RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder, I am adding the Card element of my layout to a custom AnimationHelper class which in turn should animate that Card when it is that Card's turn. My problem right now is determining when it is everyone's turn...

I've got the animation effect *kind of* working, but I need some help in figuring out how to more accurately represent the pattern. Right now, I've got a rapid "domino" effect, and it just doesn't look right. Upon further examination of the clip from the Material Documentation, it is obvious that the first cell is colored first, and then the cells below and to the right, continuing on with that pattern until all six cells have been darkened. This is where I need some help coming up with a methodology to, no matter how many rows and columns of cards there are, animate my cards to achieve this ever elusive visual design pattern.

[Here is an imgur album with a few stills from the clip](http://imgur.com/a/WOzHh) on the site to better understand how it is they achieved the effect.

Here is the link to the code on Github: github /halfjew22/AutoFitGridRecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/lustig/autofitgridrecyclerview
(Sorry, without at least 10 rep, I can't post links)

Any help, assistance, constructive criticism of my code, and suggestions for a better way of implementing this animation are very welcome.

Below are the relevant code snippets:

~~~~~~Animation Helper~~~~~

```
package com.lustig.autofitgridrecyclerview.animations;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * With this class, I am going to achieve the radial reaction effect     described on the
 *  Material Guidelines docs here:
 */

/**
 * Questions / Concerns
 *
 * How many animations can happen at one time?
 * How should I deal with that?
 * Will a simple boolean flag work for 2, 3 or more animations occurring in parallel?
 */

/**
 * I'm not worried about efficiency so much as actually doing what I want to do.
 * After I get something working, I can work on finding better ways to do things,
 * but if I bog myself down with trying to pre-optimize, ain't shit gon' get did...
 */

public class AnimationHelper {

public static final long DEFAULT_DURATION_MS = 200;

private static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTY_TO_ANIMATE = "alpha";

/* Type of property of View being animated */
private String mViewPropertyToAnimate = DEFAULT_PROPERTY_TO_ANIMATE;

/* Duration of animations, set to default value, but can be changed */
private long mAnimationDuration = DEFAULT_DURATION_MS;

/* Value to determine if an animation is currently occurring */
private boolean isCurrentlyAnimating = false;

/* First, I need an animation queue. I should use a generic view, I'll try that first */
private ArrayList<View> mViewsToAnimate = new ArrayList<View>();

/* Next I'll need a method to add to the animation queue */
public void addViewToQueue(View viewToAnimate) {

    /**
     * If I've already animated the view, don't do it again
     */
    if (viewToAnimate.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        return;
    }

    mViewsToAnimate.add(viewToAnimate);

    /* This method is the meat and potatoes of this class */
    startAnimationChain();
}

/* This method will be in charge of starting the domino effect */
private void startAnimationChain() {

    /* If there is currently not an animation happening, start one */
    if (mViewsToAnimate.size() >= 2 && !isCurrentlyAnimating) {

        animateSingleView(mViewsToAnimate.get(0));

        /**
         * If we are currently animating, just wait. The next view animation should
         * automatically be spawned
         */
    } else if (isCurrentlyAnimating) {

        // Just wait, animations should continue until the list is empty

    }

}

private void animateSingleView(final View v) {

    /* Right now, using a single animation, will change in the future */
    ObjectAnimator animator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, mViewPropertyToAnimate, 0f, 1f);

    animator.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);

    animator.addListener(
            new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    /* Remove the currently animating View from the list */
                    mViewsToAnimate.remove(v);

                    /* Notify the class Object that an animation is happening */
                    isCurrentlyAnimating = true;

                    /**
                     * If, after removing the currently animating view, the list is not empty,
                     * start the next animation after the current animation is halfway done.
                     */
                    if (!mViewsToAnimate.isEmpty()) {

                        /* Set a timer for (mAnimationDuration / 2) ms to start next animation */
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();

                        handler.postDelayed(
                            new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // Animate the first item in the list because each time
                                    // an animation starts, it is removed from the list
                                    if (!mViewsToAnimate.isEmpty()) {
                                        animateSingleView(mViewsToAnimate.get(0));
                                    }
                                }
                            }, mAnimationDuration / 6);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                    /**
                     * Setting this boolean flag could potentially cause issues as I'm going
                     * to have to use a Runnable to wait some time before starting the next
                     * animation. If there are any bugs, come back here, debug, and make sure
                     * that this flag is behaving as expected
                     */

                    /* Notify the class Object that the current animation has finished */
                    isCurrentlyAnimating = false;

                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    // Ignored intentionally
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    // Ignored intentionally
                }
            });

    animator.start();

}

}
```

~~~~~AutofitRecyclerView~~~~~

```
package com.lustig.autofitgridrecyclerview.recyclers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class AutofitRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private GridLayoutManager manager;
    private int columnWidth = -1;

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            int[] attrsArray = {
                    android.R.attr.columnWidth
            };
            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
            columnWidth = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
            array.recycle();
        }

        manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);
        setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        if (columnWidth > 0) {
            int spanCount = Math.max(1, getMeasuredWidth() / columnWidth);
            manager.setSpanCount(spanCount);
        }
    }
}
```

~~~~~Adapter and ViewHolder implementation~~~~~

```
package com.lustig.autofitgridrecyclerview.adapters;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.lustig.autofitgridrecyclerview.R;
import com.lustig.autofitgridrecyclerview.animations.AnimationHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumberedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NumberedAdapter.TextViewHolder> {

    private List<String> labels;
    private AnimationHelper mHelper;

    public NumberedAdapter(int count) {

        mHelper = new AnimationHelper();

        labels = new ArrayList<String>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            labels.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TextViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new TextViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TextViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final String label = labels.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(label);

        mHelper.addViewToQueue(holder.cardView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return labels.size();
    }

    public class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView textView;

        public TextViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need these workarounds.

Implement a custom ItemAnimator. When back arrow is pressed, remove all items from the adapter and `notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, mAdapter.getItemCount())`; 
This will call your ItemAnimator to `animateRemove` all views. There you can record views, decide on orders etc; after which you'll receive `runPendingAnimations` call where you can run actual animations.

See DefaultItemAnimator's implementation for details.

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve the removal animation, but actually the animation of adding all of the items to the RecyclerView when the activity is loaded and subsequently on scrolling. As far as I can tell, the ItemAnimator can only be called when you add or remove a value from your adapter, but not on the initial loading of all of the Views within the RecyclerView.

Comment: Oh thats actually true. RecyclerView does not run animations in the first frame because generally it is not the desired behavior. To work around that, you can start with an empty adapter and add items in the next frame using a Handler.
About the removal case, you need to communicate with your ItemAnimator to change removal behavior.

Comment: OK, so I know my pattern for loading the images is off. Could you take a peek at my AnimationHelper class? I feel like I need to just store the CardViews in my animation class in a more analogous way to how they're actually displayed on screen. [Here is a video of my current progress.](http://youtu.be/jmHsM91CnH4)  If I were to initially start with an empty adapter, how would you suggest following the actual pattern? The pattern is what I'm having the most trouble with.

Comment: Hey @yigit. Just came across this question randomly and realized who it was answering my question. I wrote this while still in college and then we ran across each other briefly at Google. Sorry since off topic, but thought that was neat. Hope you're well!